# What is a slug?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm currently working through CodeIgniters tutorial in its fantastic documentation. However there is a term that is frequently used and it's called a "slug". I've looked around a lot to find out what the term means and I can't make sense of what it is and what it's for. Here's an example of when it's used:

> With this code you can perform two different queries. You can get all
>   news records, or get a news item by its slug

Comment: Not sure if it has more meaning in CI,but in general: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing)#Slug

Comment: Then how would the following code relate:

public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
{
 if ($slug === FALSE)
 {
  $query = $this->db->get('news');
  return $query->result_array();
 }

 $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
 return $query->row_array();
}

Comment: Looks like it returns news with given slug. Just like finding by id, but instead of numerical id you provide unique slug.

Comment: What would a unique slug be though? Like a keyword?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

A slug is a part of the URL when you are accessing a resource. Say you have a URL, such as the one below, that displays all of the cars in your system:

```
http://localhost/cars
```

When you would want to reference a particular car in your system, you would provide the following URL:

```
http://localhost/cars/audi-a6/
```

Notice how the URL is still very logical, and very SEO friendly. In terms of using the slug, that's at your own discretion. The *audi-a6* string above may be a unique identifier for a car in your system — let's say that you have a relational database with the following fields:

```
id
car_name
car_brand
car_unique_identifier
```

The field `car_unique_identifier` would then be used to store the values that get displayed in the slug; in the example that I've specified above with an Audi A6 car, this is where your *audi-a6* string would live.

You may use it in other ways as well — for instance, if you have a **posts** controller that functions like a blog. The title for a page might be the slug for it, if it is URL encoded. For our article named "Best ways to make SEO better", you may provide the following URL:

```
http://localhosts/posts/best-ways-to-make-seo-better
```

You would then run `url_decode()` on the slug, and you would obtain the string *best ways to make seo better*, which you can use in order to find a post via its title.

It doesn't need to stop there — you may decide to have multiple slugs to represent something — let's take a look at how BBC is doing it. I've taken a random article from today, which has the following URL:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-24506006
```

This links to an article named: *African Union urges ICC to drop cases against leaders*. The way that BBC are doing it is that they use the last part of the slug *world-africa-24506006*, which is *24506006*, to identify a unique entry in their system. They then most likely use *world-africa* to denote the category that a post belongs to (although this may only be an assumption, it's still an educated guess).

Finally, let's imagine the following DB table, for research papers.

```
id
category
title
```

You may have an example that works like the one below.

```
http://localhost/papers
```

This URL represents all of the research papers currently in the system. You would then be able to access all of the research papers on physics via the following slug:

```
http://localhost/papers/physics
```

Our slug is *physics*, and our database select currently looks something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM papers
WHERE LOWER(papers.category) = 'physics'
```

You may then expose the following URL:

```
http://localhost/papers/physics/gravitation
```

Now our slug is composed of **physics** and **gravitation**. Our query behind the scenes may look something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM papers
WHERE LOWER(papers.category) = 'physics'
AND LOWER(papers.title) = 'gravitation'
```

This allows us to uniquely identify an entry in our system.

So we've used slugs repeatedly in order to filter out our information. In the example, when we ran the URL without any slugs:

```
http://localhost/papers
```

We wanted to list all of the research papers available. When we ran the URL with the *physics* slug:

```
http://localhost/papers/physics
```

We wanted to list all of the research papers on *physics*, thus narrowing our results. Finally, when we provided two slugs, we could uniquely identify an entry in our system.

```
http://localhost/papers/physics/gravitation
```

Could we have modeled this differently? Of course! Depending on our system's requirements, we can normalise and denormalise our relational tables. We could have had a permalink system in place, so that our posts table looked like this:

```
 id
 title
 permalink
```

We might then have had the following entry:

```
 | 20013 | Gravitation | physics-gravitation-breakthrough |
```

Thus exposing the URL:

```
 http://localhost/papers/physics-gravitation-breakthrough
```

In the example above, the slug **physics-gravitation-breakthrough** allows us to uniquely identify a post via:

```sql
 SELECT *
 FROM papers
 WHERE papers.permalink = physics-gravitation-breakthrough
```

Comment: Is there any possibility where I can change the URL like : http://localhost/audi-a6/ this. I don't want the parent to be included in the UR.

Answer (score 103):

**Short answer**

It's the `what-is-a-slug` part in the URL of this question.

Comment: Short and creative! :)

Answer (score 14):

"slug" is totally context dependent word, but in programming or as far as this question is concerned here "slug" refers to a URL. We know that a [URL can't contain every character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid). That's why when any post, page, controller have these typed to title so its slug is used as URL. Which might be automatically derived.

So in one line, slug is a *URL friendly version* of any name.

Answer (score 4):

The following is an example of a slug:

```
 <?php
 function create_slug($string){
  $slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);
  return $slug;
   }
  echo create_slug('does this thing work or not');
   //returns 'does-this-thing-work-or-not'
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers given above are correct but I want to answer directly to the question.
**Slug** in the Codeigniter tutorial example refers to the URL "**news**". If you don't have "news" as your $slug or slug in your database and you run this url in your browser "index.php/news/view" will return error 404_page not found.
I encountered this problem until I read the above answers which gave me the understanding of what Slug meant.
I change my slug to news in the database table.
Slug is like a pointer.