# After updating the post, I want the user to be redirected to the post (Django - Python)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, schema, slug

I want the user to be able to update existing posts. When the user clicks Update, then Post, they get an error message saying there is no URL to direct to. But the post does get updated on the backend.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I thought the line `return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})` would redirect them back to their original post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content =  models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    #url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Here is the table schema.

```
sqlite> .schema blog_post
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "blog_post" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "title" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "content" text NOT NULL, "url" varchar(500) NOT NULL, "author_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "date_posted" datetime NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX "blog_post_url_5af1045a" ON "blog_post" ("url");
CREATE INDEX "blog_post_author_id_dd7a8485" ON "blog_post" ("author_id");
sqlite>
```

**views.py**

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
    path('facebook/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='blog/index.html'), name="facebook")
]
```

**Update**

I use to have `self.url= slugify(self.title)` and I changed to `self.url= slugify(self.id)`. Because to access my posts, you put in the ID number and not title. Unfortunately the problem persisted.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content =  models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    #url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.id)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[image]

**Update 2**

I am now getting this error message.

Reverse for 'article_detail' not found. 'article_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your views?

Comment: I have now added them to my original post.

Comment: can you also add your urls.py?

Comment: I have now added them to my original post.

Comment: you don't have any model field named **`slug`**, so the usage `self.slug` is doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Do I need to change it to self.url?

Comment: Also, you should be more aware of what is a slug (probably this could help you - [What is a Slug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335215/what-is-a-slug)) because you have passed a *integer* value to the `slugify()` function, which also doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I get what you are saying. My focus at the moment is getting the Update feature to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix `get_absolute_url`.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: I am just testing that now.

Comment: I unfortunately still got the error message Reverse for 'article_detail' not found. 'article_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Go to your models.py. Replace your `get_absolute_url` function with the function above.

Comment: Thank you very much